# Access related member with IL Emit

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, il

how can I write this C# method

```
public bool CheckIsLocal()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
}
```

using C# Reflection.Emit?

this method is just a example, my intention is discover how to write code to access related members using C# Reflection.Emit.

Comment: Self sufficiency FTW. Why not write the code and take a peek in LinqPad or a decompiler (ILSpy?)

Comment: *unclear what you're asking*

Comment: I rewrite question to be more clear.

Comment: What is `related members`? Do you mean `Reflection` or `Reflection.Emit`? Please explain  what you want to do, not what you think is the way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Func<bool> GenerateCheckIsLocal() {

            var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("CheckIsLocal", typeof(bool), Type.EmptyTypes, true);

            var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(HttpContext).GetProperty("Current").GetMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(HttpContext).GetProperty("Request").GetMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(HttpRequest).GetProperty("IsLocal").GetMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            return dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<bool>)) as Func<bool>;
        }
```

Something like this should work i think.